# Разные файлы robots.txt на одном хостинге для разных доменов

Tags: .htaccess

Приветствую всех господа

Есть такая штука robots.txt. Есть адовое кол-во доменов направленное на 1 хостинг. Можно ли при разных хостингах использовать перенаправление (.htaccess) на разные robots.txt файлы?

```
при домен1/robots.txt - папка1/robots.txt
при домен2/robots.txt - папка35/robots.txt
при домен3/robots.txt - папка999/robots.txt
```

p.s. наверно все на до мной посмеються но думал так (видимо не правильно)

```
RewriteCond http://site1.ru/robots.txt ^rew1/robots.txt [NC]
RewriteCond http://site2.ru/robots.txt ^rew35/robots.txt [NC]
RewriteCond http://site3.ru/robots.txt ^rew999/robots.txt [NC]
```

Comment: можно, правда непонятно что именно хочется и в чем сложность ?

Comment: На определый файл послать, при определенном адресе, если коротко. Подскажете как написать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

все домены на одну директорию указывают ? Если да, то:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} domain1.com$   #включая субдомены
Rewriterule ^robots.txt$ dir1/robots.txt [L]

RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.ru$
Rewriterule ^robots.txt$ dir2/robots.txt [L]
```

Comment: Работает. Это гениально!